# How can I thicken a fluid? And sticky

Tags: pest-control

The particular fluid is ant bait. I'm not sure of its ingredients. It's gel like but too watery. I want to smear gobs of it onto a vertical surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silica microballoons work nicely for epoxy.

For ant bait, probably cornstarch.